# Imaginary Part of meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm currently studying DeBranges book about Hilbert Spaces of Entire functions. This questions deals with problem 60 on page 61 (page 71 in the pdf on his website [DeBranges Website](https://www.math.purdue.edu/people/bio/branges/Papers)).
Let $s_n,t_n$ be (potentially infinite unbounded) positive sequences such that $s_n<t_n<s_{n+1}<t_{n+1}$ (interlacing property) and let
$$f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-z/t_n}{1-z/s_n},\qquad z\neq s_n.$$
Then $f$ defines a meromorphic function with only simple, real poles and zeros on $\mathbb{C}$ which is real for real $z$. I want to show that it is in fact real if, and only if, $z$ is real. I tried working with a few examples and found the following problems:

Let's go finite first. If we disregard the poles, then there is an easy counterexample:
$$f(z)=(z-1)(z+1)=z^2-1,\qquad \text{then }f(\mathrm{i})=-2\in\mathbb{R}.$$
Okay, the poles are relevant here. In particular
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z},\qquad \text{then }\Im(f(a+\mathrm{i}b))=\frac{b(a^2+1+b^2)}{a^2+b^2}\neq 0\quad \text{for }b\neq 0.$$

But why? What part of the pole property makes this work, if we multiply by a pole? Is it the interlacing part? Again, but why?

I tried computing the Imaginary part of finite products - there it actually works out. By partial fraction decomposition we obtain the following sum
$$f_n(z)=h+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{G_n(s_k)}{F_n'(s_k)(z-s_k)},\qquad\text{where } h\in\mathbb{R},\;G_n(z)=\underbrace{\prod_{k=1}^n (1-z/t_k)}_{\text{numerator}},\;F_n(z)=\underbrace{\prod_{k=1}^n(1-z/s_k)}_{\text{denominator}}$$
by computing the residues. The interlacing property of the zeros and poles guarantees that $G_n/F_n'$ doesn't change sign and thus we get a positive imaginary part for $z\in\mathbb{C}^+$. The problem arises now if we take the limit to infinity, because then the strict inequality might become an equality. So once again I don't see a reason why the imaginary part shouldn't be zero.

I would much appreciate any input. My only idea would be to do a partial fraction decomposition on all of $f$, but there I don't see why it should converge at all. Is there some result I don't know which allows me to do the decomposition on all potentially infinite poles?

Comment: It is shown here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1609741/42969 that such a function maps the upper half plane onto itself (and consequently, the lower half plane onto the lower half plane).

Comment: Thank you! This is apparently much easier than I thought and the solution is exactly what I needed. Am I supposed to delete my question now or mark it as duplicate or anything? Would you mind letting me know how to do that?

Comment: There is no reason to delete the question. I have closed it as a duplicate.